# swf to Illustrator friendly format (vector)

Tags: flash, svg, adobe-illustrator

So I'm making a drawing app that uses flash. I want to be able to export my drawing into an illustrator friendly format.

I'm thinking I will need to record the shapes drawn with a "history" and then export those either via text/xml/bytearray.

Have any fellow overflowers heard of tool to make my life easier? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export to something that Illustrator can import as defined shapes and paths then use SVG.  You can generate the SVG from Flash (not automatically, manually) and then Illustrator can import it.

One technique I've seen is to create a wrapper for the underlying Graphics instance on the DisplayObject you're drawing to.  Override all the primitive drawing calls (moveTo, lineTo, etc) with your own that record what was done and then call the originals.  This way you can have a full history to write out to SVG.

Comment: Oh nice, using overrides. That sounds like it may be the way to go if nothing out there already exists. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I don't think this kind of solution actually exists. At least you are not providing any details. Normally you would use the authoring file (.fla) which has some export capabilities, except for SVG. If you really want SVG (like I did), it's worth the effort to take a look at the swf specification documentation.

Comment: @esims, This answer is from my own work experience. I have done it. It was over 11 years ago so I don't remember if there was a 3rd party library I used to help or if I had a custom implementation that overrode the methods I mentioned. I think it was custom but not hard to translate those calls to SVG elements as both use the same information. That said, Flash and Flex are both effectively dead, so this is ancient history anyways.

Answer (score 5):

Install a PDF printer driver like this one http://www.pdf995.com/ (it's free with a few annoying ads)

Export your FLA > SWF

Open SWF and right click on the SWF window > Print

Choose the PDF printer driver and print to file

Open the resulting PDF in Illustrator CC

Vectors are preserved!

Answer (score 2):

Joshua Davis used to save/print it as a pdf/PostScript file, and then open it in Illustrator...

[EDIT]

And it seems that it is still possible.

I installed a PostScript printer that prints to file (kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404883.html), I am running windows vista and installed a Canon PS-NX5000.

I've tried 2 different swfs in the standalone player, one which draws rectangles and another which draws lines.

Right-Click>Print...>Canon PS-NX5000>Print.

Enter a file name with a .ai extension. Open in Illustrator. Select all and ungroup/break apart. Assets are vectors. Job Done!

Comment: The only problem is that the saved pdf/ps is a bitmap image so I lose all the vector info :(  However, I am going to use something like this for another part of the application (eg saving your art to show others).

Comment: I'm fairly confident that saving it as a PostScript file preserves all the vectors. Joshua has being doing this for years and I have read about it many times... I believe I have done it myself in the past. You can see from Joshua's video description here http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=498588000076 I can't find any step-by-step instructions, but I do remember it involved downloading a PostScript printer driver... ?

Comment: I did more research on postscript and I can see that it CAN carry the necessary data. I did a print-postscript which turns all the fonts to vector, but turns any flash to a bitmap. I assume I'll have to do some custom conversion similar to if I was going to convert to svg. Regardless, thanks for one-upping me on this information. Before now I never realized postscript held any vector data. If it hadn't been for your comment, I would have never known!

Comment: I'm going to be looking at doing this sort of thing again in the next few weeks. So I will be interested in how you get on. I know that gradients and filters never worked well, but things might have changed. I would also assume that cacheAsBitmap might cause some issues, but I don't really know. I've been finding a trail of comments, but no actual tutorial/steps eg. http://www.flickr.com/groups/generatorx/discuss/72157606072410204/ ... I might do some experiments now and see how I get on....

Comment: Alright, a couple of quick tests have returned some positive results.

Comment: I installed a PostScript printer that prints to file (http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404883.html), I am running windows vista and installed a Canon PS-NX5000. I've run 2 different swfs in the standalone player, one which draws rectangles and another which draws lines, right-click>Print...>Canon PS-NX5000>Print. Enter a file name with a .ai extension. Open in Illustrator. Select all and ungroup/break apart. Assets are vectors. Job Done!

Answer (score 0):

I use this online tool http://iiistudio.com/convert2svg/

It works the best and save the result in SVG format you can directly open with Adobe Illustrator, and it's made in flash application. You can download the swf file and it could work locally without server backend anyway as I guessed it has php or js!

As I tried to import the swf file I exported from Toon Boom Harmony to Adobe Flash, it's into the stage but the vector curves are zig-zagged not what I want. Ans I also tried print the swf to PDF with variety of virtual PDF printer such as Foxit PDF printer, PDF Factory Pro and the results is bad as well, not the original shapes at all.

results are so different in PDF, Flash and swf2svg:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bJnf.jpg

Comment: Direct download link for this flash application http://iiistudio.com/convert2svg/sPjI.swf